# Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: with capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-11.04, ruby-1.9.3

I can install capybara-webkit on Mac, when I deployed code on Ubuntu, I am facing below error

```
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 


    Gem files will remain installed in /home/datas/.bundler/tmp/7940/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/datas/.bundler/tmp/7940/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/./gem_make.out

   An error occured while installing capybara-webkit (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Even I tried with `sudo gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.12.1'`

I am getting same error.

Comment: There is probably a missing library.

Please paste the content of the file : /home/datas/.bundler/tmp/7940/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/./gem_make.out

Comment: @Intrepidd - Only one like inside gem_make.out here it is

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install libqt4-dev and it will fix your problem

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

read [this one](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/113) for more information.

Please let me know if you have still problem on this

Answer (score 7):

capybara-webkit depends on a WebKit implementation from Qt, a cross-platform development toolkit. You'll need to download the Qt libraries to build and install the gem. capybara-webkit 0.12.x depends on Qt >= 4.6 and capybara-webkit 0.13+ depends on Qt >= 4.7. You can check your version of Qt by running qmake -v.

If you get an error when building, along the lines of fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory, you might be attempting the build against Qt3. Either uninstall Qt3, or make sure that the qmake in your PATH links to Qt4. [...more](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit)

For those getting this error on Mac, try this:

```
brew update

brew install qt

bundle
```